# This page isn’t working - (ip_addr) is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 while running Laravel in ubunto 16.04 vps

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, vps

I am trying upload my `laravel` project to `vps linux ubuntu 16.04 hosting`.

I installed `apache2, php7.2, mariadb-server`. and also tested with `apache2` by adding some `index.php` with `phpinfo()`; content everything working fine.

now I cloned my `laravel` project to `/var/www/` folder and changed my `laravel.conf` and enabled it. but now when i open the ip addresss in browser i get this error mentioned in title. i tested by putting some `echo` statements in my `index.php` file the code is breaking at

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

and I dont get any `network log` to check if server is sending any `error code` also.

tried to search in internet for many solution and i tried everything but no result. so any one who used laravel in vps please advice how to go about.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone thanks for viewing my question

What i did was?

1. I reinstalled `ubuntu 16.04` in my `vps` so that every data was deleted.
2. And started with installing everything freshly this type i did not install `php7.2` but i installed `php` only by default it installed `php7.0` for me.
3. With this I installed `laravel` project from `composer` and it downloaded `laravel 5.5` for me and when i changed `.env-example` to `.env` and run `php artisan key:generate` it started working for me. only i had to do `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/project/storage`
4. Now I cloned my `laravel` project from `github` and did `composer update` but it said `php7.1 is required` as my `laravel` project was `5.6 version`.
5. I again installed `software-properties-common` and `add-apt-respository ppa:ondrej/php and php7.1` and `composer update`.
6. after installing packages I changed `.env-example` to `.env` and run `key:generate` and also i changed `conf` file and `reload server` with new `conf` enabled. But this time again same issue is arising as stated in the question.
7. Again I installed new `laravel` project with newly installed `php7.1` and this time it downloaded `laravel 5.6` key was generated automatically and i changed `conf` file and reload apache2. again the issue is same as stated in question.
8. Now i am deciding it could be some issue with `php7.1` installation and `laravel 5.6` project in `ubuntu 16.04`. and i have to downgrade myself to `laravel 5.5` and then upload my project.
9. Laravel 5.6 demands php7.1 and it gives some cypher related error with php7.0 this i remember and presenting it for your info.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether Laravel index.php is inside the public folder & please check your apache vhost is configured properly.

Comment: did you set the laravel app key

Comment: hi i will give my ip address will you please check once with your ssh client

Comment: sorry for the link.

Comment: @SunilKumar - instead of sharing anything i would suggest you 2 things:
use - 1. laravel forge  (easy and not expensive)
or 
2. google search for "serversforhackers php" you issue will get resolved.